# TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects when trying to fit a KerasRegressor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm trying to train a neural network and at no point does it appear that `pickle` is even being used, so I'm somewhat confused. Here's the details:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X.shape
(149, 8)

y.shape
(149,)

# define base model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(149, input_dim=149, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(75))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model(), epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=2)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=3)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Which is where the problem arises...

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callable function as `build_fn` in `KerasRegressor`. Removing the rounds brackets should make it works.

Following your code, chage:

```
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model(), epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=2)
```

into:

```
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=2)
```